# KIVY GUI with buildozer and scipy got big problem

Tags: python, android, user-interface, kivy

from scipy import integrate, special, e

I am trying to use scipy with my kivy GUI app but it crashes after completely compiling it to android and run it
is there any other alternative libraries that offer calculus and integrals methods?

**what I want is to successfully include the scipy library inside the bulldozer.spec file**

```
[ERROR]: Build failed: arm-linux-androideabi-gfortran not found. See https://github.com/mzakharo/android-gfortran

Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=statal --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy==2.0.0,scipy --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.